# Redirect email from a shorter domain name to a longer one

Tags: networking, email, website, redirection

I'm new to website management including DNS and MX records.

Here's my scenario.  My company has an official domain: reallylongandcomplicatedname.com.

They bought a shorter name:  easyname.com.

They want emails such as john@easyname.com to be delivered to john@reallylongandcomplicatedname.com.

Is this possible?  What do I need to do?  I've tried googling but I'm not really sure what I'm looking for, and am not sure what to do from here.

Comment: The first step is to point the short domain's MX records to your mail server. The second step depends very much on what mail server you are using, and in which configuration. (For example, postfix or exim or Exchange? "Local" or "virtual" accounts?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Set your DNS MX record for the new short domain to be the same as for your full long name.
2. Configure your mail server to host both
3. Create rewrite rule to rewrite  @shortname as @longname

Comment: It doesn't even need to be a rewrite rule (and indeed is probably better not being, as you'll find out the first time that people complain that customers are getting surprise replies from the wrong domain).  You just need to tell your MTS that both domains share the same single set of mailboxes/accounts.

Comment: Your steps are in the wrong order.  First configure the mail server, THEN change the MX records.  The stated order has emails being delivered to a mail server that isn't configured to accept them, which could mean dropped emails under some circumstances.